# How can you replace a character at a specific index in a line in vim?

Tags: shell, vim, replace, sed

I need to replace a character (it can be either X, L,H,1,0) in a specific index in some specific line in a file using `vim/sed/awk` etc.

Eg:

File:

```
0101010HLHLHLHL
1010100LHHHLHLH
1000000HHLLHHLL
LHLHLHLHLLLLHLH
```

So I need to replace 8th character in line 2 to `X`.

```
0101010HLHLHLHL
1010100XHHHLHLH
1000000HHLLHHLL
LHLHLHLHLLLLHLH
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this `sed`:

```
sed '2s/./X/8' file
```

Use `-i` options for in-place edit.

Here,

- `2` - Line number
- `s/./X/8` - Replaces any character `.` (matches any one character) to `X` at `8th` occurrence only.

Answer (score 2):

My first piece of `ed`!

```
ed -s file <<<$'e\n2s/./X/8\nw'
```

There are 3 commands each separated by a newline `\n`. I'm using bash so I've gone for the combination of a herestring `<<<` to pass the command via standard input and a "C string" with `$''` so that I can use `\n` for newlines.

The three commands are:

- `e`: edit
- `2/s/./X/8`: on the second line, substitute the 8th character for `X`
- `w` write the file

`-s` suppresses any output from the command.

Answer (score 2):

with GNU awk for gensub():

```
$ awk -v i=8 'NR==2{$0 = gensub(/./,"X",i)} 1' file
0101010HLHLHLHL
1010100XHHHLHLH
1000000HHLLHHLL
LHLHLHLHLLLLHLH
```

With other awks:

```
$ awk -v i=8 'NR==2{$0 = substr($0,1,8-1) "X" substr($0,i+1)} 1' file
0101010HLHLHLHL
1010100XHHHLHLH
1000000HHLLHHLL
LHLHLHLHLLLLHLH
```

Answer (score 0):

In Vim, if you are in the file at line 1:

```
j8lrX
```

If you are on another line:

```
2G8lrX
```

If you are not in the file:

```
vim file +2 +normal\!\ 8lrX
```

- The `+2` means : open file and move the cursor in line 2.
- The `+normal\!\ 8lrXZZ` means: execute `:normal! 8lrX` inside vim.

You can also save directly with `ZZ`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a vim one-liner for this: `:2,2s/\(.\{7\}\)./\1X/`

Explanation:

1. `:2,2s///` makes sure you replace on the 2nd line only.
2. `^\(.\{7\}\).` matches the first 7 chars into a group, then the 8th char outside of the group
3. `\1X` is the replacement: `\1` is the first group matched, i.e. the first 7 chars. Then `X` is the replacement you specified.